# How can i get the total of the 2 rows that i subtract?

Tags: laravel, alias

```php
public function vparticulardiscountamount($id)
{
    $fetch = DB::table('tbl_payment_user_map')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_payment_particular', 'tbl_payment_user_map.payment_particular', '=', 
          'tbl_payment_particular.id')
        ->leftJoin('tbl_discount', 'tbl_payment_user_map.discount', '=', 'tbl_discount.id')
        ->select('tbl_payment_particular.amount','tbl_discount.amount as 
         discountamount',DB::raw('(tbl_payment_particular.amount - tbl_discount.amount) as 
          total'))
        ->where('tbl_payment_user_map.payment_user',$id)
        ->get();

        return response()->json(['results' => $fetch], 200);
}
```

Comment: do you want to get sum of both two column  `tbl_payment_particular.amount` and `tbl_discount.amount` values?

Comment: hello this is the results in postman

i want to get  sum of all total
{
    "results": [
        {
            "amount": 18800,
            "discountamount": 15,
            "total": 18785
        },
        {
            "amount": 5000,
            "discountamount": 10,
            "total": 4990
        },
        {
            "amount": 2000,
            "discountamount": 10,
            "total": 1990
        },
        {
            "amount": 4070,
            "discountamount": 50,
            "total": 4020
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `Collection`'s `sum` method and add the result to your response.

```php
return response()
    ->json(['results' => $fetch, 'sum' => $fetch->sum('total')], 200);
```

or

```
return response()
    ->json(['results' => ['data' => $fetch, 'sum' => $fetch->sum('total')]], 200);
```

Comment: this code worked
thank you so much :)